# Which table hold the tax for sales order?

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I create SSRS report that read data from Sales order in AX 2012.

In my SSRS report I want to calculate Total Amount and VAT for the Sales Order but i can't find where can get the tax for sales order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple answer for this, but you should not use the tables your self, but use the class [SalesTotals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/salestotals.aspx) to calculate.

You may also consider looking at class `SalesConfirmDP` to see how in does its job.